# Getting all users that created an item today in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to make a list of all users that created an item.

These items have the row `user_id`

To get all items created today, I do this:

```
$items = Item::whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'));
```

Now I want to perform a query that gives me all users who have created an item today. There will be users who created 1000 items, and there will be users that didn't do anything at all.

I could do this with `->unique()` but there must surely be a better way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `items` relationship set on your `User` model you could do something like:

```
$users = User::whereHas('items', function ($query) {
   $query->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::today());
})->get();
```